# sending results with res.render shows duplicate lines

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I must be doing something really stupid, but I cannot find what. I want to list the documents in a MongoDB collection, very simply. I am using nodejs, mongoose, and Jade (I know should move to Pug) and I want to keep everything simple, it is to be able to view the data for maintenance purpose.

Here is my jade file:

```
extends layout

block content
  .uk-container(align="center")
    br
    table.uk-table(width="100%")
      thead
        tr
          th username
          th firstlogin
          th lastlogin
      tbody
        #{results}
```

this is my route:

```
 router.get('/ListUsers',function(req, res, next) {
 // need to check the validity of the person   
    Account.find({'schema':'toto'}, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err); // we should not have an error, it means db has pb
    } else {
      var userList ="";
      user.forEach(function(record){
        userList+="<tr><td>"+record.nomuser+"</td><td>"+record.firstlogin+"</td><td>"+record.lastlogin+"</td></tr>";
      })     
      console.log(userList); // it is perfect and if put in the jade shows perfectly well 
      res.render('super_user_list',{results:userList});
    }
  });
});  // end ListUsers
```

The rendering baffles me:

first at the top I have in the middle (which does not show if I put the console.log result directly in Jade)

```
 <>>
```

which I don't understand where it comes from. And then my recordset is duplicated.

What is it that I am doing wrong ? I wanted a simple page without additional javascript etc and I find myself with a mystery I cannot solve ! :(

Thanks for any idea, suggestion explanation !

Comment: It seems strange that you're generating HTML inside your code while you're also using a templating engine.

Comment: Is `user`, on which you're running your `forEach` an array or an object?

Comment: @robertklep yes i know, but I and doing this fast- I thought! and would like to understand what is going on, in case I need to do this once.

Comment: @DakshShah it returns an array of all matching mongoose documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're already using a templating engine, there's no need to separately generate HTML in your route. That's the whole point of using templating engines. Here's something that should accomplish what you're trying to achieve.

Your new route should look something like this:

```
router.get('/ListUsers',function(req, res, next) {
    Account.find({'schema':'toto'}, function(err, user) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
          // pass matched documents to template 
          res.render('super_user_list', { results: user });
      }
    });
});
```

The template file can now work on your results:

```
extends layout

block content
  .uk-container(align="center")
    br
    table.uk-table(width="100%")
      thead
        tr
          th username
          th firstlogin
          th lastlogin
      tbody
      each record in results
        td= record.nomuser
        td= record.firstlogin
        td= record.lastlogin
```

Let me know if you know if you need any clarifications!

Comment: yes this works. I wanted to be able to send HTML to change the color of some of the cells depending on the value. I was hoping to do that without writing a javascript file on the client. I still don't understand why what I did does not work, since the Html is correct.

Comment: It just hit me (must be the heat of the day that was res.rendering my brain sluggish) that of course I cannot pass the HTML like this since it gets inside the template. If I want to change the colours of the cells I would need to pass some jade templating code (??) so that it is reworked in the template. Maybe I just go back and write the client javascript, might be easier.